# Bot Framework ResumeDialogAsync not firing

Tags: botframework

I am now trying to find whether or not my authentication dialog has finished and a result retrieved. My authentication dialog ends with a 
`return await sc.EndDialogAsync(tokenResponse);`
 I am trying to catch the tokenResponse in the callback to my main dialog but the ResumeDialogAsync does not get triggered in either the Authentication dialog or the Main dialog.
What am I missing?

Comment: Please share more of the code (Main dialog and Authentication dialog)

Comment: @EricDahlvang I think the issue was the fact that my dialog was contained in a waterfall dialog so the token was passed to the calling dialog not to the resume dialog async method.

Comment: If you have an answer for your question, please add and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being an issue with how the dialog was being called, in the Enterprise Bot template it uses a non-waterfall dialog to start the ComponentDialog AuthenticationDialog, by changing the initial dialog to a waterfall dialog the token is returned and the authentication works as expected.